# Find a JIRA user by e-mail address with JIRA REST API

Tags: java, jira-rest-api

I'm using JIRA REST API for accessing JIRA from a third party application.

I'm trying to find whether a user account exists in JIRA for a particular e-mail address. The same is working for user name but not for e-mail address.

Could you please let me know how to do it? I have gone through [this](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e503) documentation.

Answer (score 2):

According to the document you linked, the REST call

```
api/2/groupuserpicker
```

searches by username OR email address.

```
parameter    type    description
------------ ------- --------------------------------------------------------
query        string  A string used to search username, Name or e-mail address
```

If it's not working with an email address then you should be submitting a support request to Atlassian.